# Another php array looping question

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Been battling with this one for what seems, like forever.

I have an array:

```
$url_array
```

It contains this info:

```
Array ( 
   [ppp] => Array ( 
      [0] => stdClass Object ( 
         [id] => 46660 
         [entity_id] => 0 
         [redirect_url] => http://www.google.com 
         [type] => Image 
      ) 
      [1] => stdClass Object ( 
         [id] => 52662 
         [entity_id] => 0 
         [pixel_redirect_url] => http://www.yahoo.com 
         [type] => Image 
      ) 
      [2] => stdClass Object ( 
         [id] => 53877 
         [entity_id] => 0 
         [redirect_url] => http://www.msn.com 
         [pixel_type] => Image 
      ) 
   ) 
   [total_count] => 3 
)
```

I need to loop through it, and do things to each variable. I can get this to work:

```
foreach ($piggies_array as $key => $value) {
$id = $value[0]->id;
$redirect_url = $value[0]->redirect_url; }
```

Not unsurprisingly, it's only echoing the first value of those variables, but no matter what I try I cannot get it to loop through:

```
$value->redirect_url;
$value=>redirect_url;
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you looping through `$url_array` or through `$url_array['ppp']`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach ($url_array['ppp'] as $key => $object) {
    echo $object->redirect_url;
}
```

Comment: best solution, only one loop.

Comment: Thanks. 1 loop works for me and with the other posts I understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the array twice.

```
foreach($piggies as $piggy) {

foreach($piggy as $key=>$value) {

$id = $value->id;
$redirect_url = $value->redirect_url; 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your doing $id = $value[0]->id which will only do the statments for the 0 element

you need a for loo

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($piggies_array['ppp']); $i++)
{
    $id = $value[$i]->id;
    $redirect_url = $value[$i]->redirect_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains another array by calling `$value[0]` you are only asking for the first item in the second array. You will need two loops, not forgetting the value may not be an array:

```
    foreach ($piggies as $var)
    {
        if (is_array($var))
        {
            foreach ($var as $obj)
            {
                echo $obj->redirect_url;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo $var;
        }
    }
```

The above *(not tested)* will output each URL and will also output the total count item of the first array.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the first dimension of the array, which only haves the `"ppp"` element. Check your code, and you'll see that you're actually asking for the first element of the array, when you have 3 elements.

What you have to do is, iterate into the array of objects (`$url_array["ppp"]`).

When you're in doubt about what you're actually iterating, a good way to start debuggin it, is printing every iteration step. If you do this with the example that you've posted, you'll see this:

```
Array( [0] => stdClass [...], [1] => stdClass [...] ... )
```

doing this:

```
foreach ($piggies_array as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Looking at this, you'll automatically find out what your problem is. So, changing it to:

```
foreach ($piggies_array['ppp'] as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

You'll have the result you want:

```
Object ( id: ... )
Object ( id: ... )
Object ( id: ... )
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

loop like this (assuming that `$piggies_array` is the same as `$url_array` you dumped):

```
foreach ($piggies_array['ppp'] as $key => $value) {
   $id = $value->id;
   $redirect_url = $value->redirect_url; 
}
```

and watch out because some of the items in 'ppp' array will not have a property redirect_url (hte second one has a pixel_redirect_url property instead.